# change value of python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

iam trying to make a color selection with python at some course that iam studying and face problem with this part of code

```
red_threshold = 0
grean_threshold = 0
blue_threshold = 0

rgb_threshold = [red_threshold,grean_threshold,blue_threshold]

thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0])|(image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1])|(image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
color_selection[thresholds] = [0,0,0]
```

the problem with 'color_selection[thresholds] = [0,0,0]'
can someone explain how this line works

and thank you in advance

Comment: Which part don’t you understand? Have you tried printing all the relevant variables? Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `image` is an *n×n×3* array, then `thresholds` is an *n×n* array of booleans. Indeed we calculate `thresholds` as:

```
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0])|
             (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1])|
             (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
```

So here the `threshold[i,j]` will be `True` if and only if the red channel has a value for that pixel (so `image[i,j,0]`) is lower than the `red_threshold`; or the green channel has a value for that pixel (so `image[i,j,1]`) is lower than the `green_threshold`; or the blue channel has a value for that pixel (so `image[i,j,2]`) is lower than the `blue_threshold`.

Next for the elements for which that `threshold[i,j]` is `True`, we will assign `color_selection[i,j,0] = 0`, `color_selection[i,j,1] = 0`, and `color_selection[i,j,2] = 0`. This is because if you index with a boolean array, it works as masking.

See the section on [*boolean or mask index arrays* of the numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) for more information.